# PDF mail attachment send with spring-boot is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, email

I have set up a MimeMessageHelper object to send email with attachment.
My problem is when  try to add a PDF attachment to the mail. The file is empty when received.
There is no problem with other file format like TXT, and the content of the mail is also valid.

My code (I skip the config of the MimeMessageHelper since it seems to work):

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(...);
// ....

ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("mypdf.pdf");
File file = resource.getFile(); 

message.addAttachment(file.getName(), file);
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: When packaged as an jar/war there is no file, only an `InputStream`. A `File` has to point to a physical file on the filesystem. A file inside an archive isn't physically on the filesystem, hence `resource.getFile()` will return `null` in this case.

Comment: It's not null since I can send TXT file with actual content (I've tried it).

Comment: Regardless you cannot reference a resource from inside jars as a file. You will need an input stream. Just do `message.addAttachment(resource.getFilename(), resource)`. There is a method that takes an `InputStreamSource` which is implementation by `Resource` and thus `ClassPathResource`.

Comment: I've tried to send the ressource but it is the same result, empty file. The size isn't 0 so it's weird...

Comment: And the pdf is readable and available? Is it in the location you are reading it from?

Comment: The pdf is in src/main/ressource. I can open it and see the content.

Comment: Is it directly in `src/main/resources`? If it is passing that resource should send the attachment.

Comment: Yes it is. There is also a TXT file at the same location, when I'm attaching it to the mail, the content is present

Comment: Could it be related to encodage? Because the pdf I'm trying to send is on ANSI and the attachment received is UTF-8.